# Cronfile did not execute sudo -u line?

Tags: linux, cron, suse

I have made the following cronjob sh file :

```
Vi RestartServices.sh


/etc/init.d/b1s stop
sleep 10
/etc/init.d/sapb1servertools stop
sleep 10
sudo -u ndbadm /usr/sap/NDB/HDB00/HDB stop
sleep 20
sudo -u ndbadm /usr/sap/NDB/HDB00/HDB start
sleep 10
/etc/init.d/sapb1servertools start
sleep 10
/etc/init.d/b1s start
```

When I run this file manually the job runs correctly.

When scheduled in crontab  (root user)

Crontab content:

```
# srvmagtCron: restarts daemons that died
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * * /bin/sh -c "[ -x     /etc/srvmagt/srvmagtCron ] && /etc/srvmagt/srvmagtCron"
0 2 * * * /hanamnt/shared/NDB/HDB00/backup/scripts/VGRbackup.sh
#RESTARTS SERVICE LAYER , SAPB1ServerTools service , HDB
0 3 * * * /hanamnt/shared/NDB/HDB00/backup/scripts/RestartServices.sh
```

It does get started at the requested time but I think it failed to execute the sudo line as the HDB service has not been restarted.

I'm trying to find out why? 
Is it because sudo cannot be executed in a cronjob? 
(service needs to start using user ndbadm)

path:
  /opt/sap/sapjvm_6//bin:/opt/fujitsu/bwai/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:/usr/lib64/jvm/jre/bin:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin

Comment: Show *exactly* your script (with four spaces in front of each code line) and your `crontab` entry. Read more about [PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) - it probably is different in your `crontab` and in your terminal, and you should show it too. So **edit your question** to improve it a lot. Is your script executable?

Comment: BTW `sudo` can be used in a cronjob (but you might prefer `/bin/su` in  your specific case), but you may need to configure more your `/etc/sudoers` file

Comment: Please **format your question appropriately:** four spaces in front of every code or command line!  Also show your `PATH` - output of `echo $PATH` at least!

Comment: You still need to edit again. I guess that some `<br/>` are wrong

Comment: Apologies im new to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a non-standard [`$PATH`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) and [crond(8)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cron.8.html) is running your [crontab(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html) entries with a shorter `$PATH`. See also [environ(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/environ.7.html), [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html) and [execvp(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html) with [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html)

My recommendation would be to write a complete shell script, and put only that in crontab. So don't use `sh -c` in  crontab entries, and set explicitly the `PATH` (either, and preferably, in the shell scripts your `crontab` entry is firing, or maybe in  your `crontab` file).

You could for example have

```
0,5,10,15,20,25,30,35,40,45,50,55 * * * *  /hanamnt/shared/srvmagt.sh
```

in your crontab, and have an *executable* `/hanamnt/shared/srvmagt.sh` file starting with

```
#!/bin/bash
export PATH=/opt/sap/sapjvm_6//bin:/opt/fujitsu/bwai/bin:/sbin:\
/usr/sbin:/usr/local/sbin:/root/bin:/usr/local/bin:\
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/bin/X11:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/games:\
/usr/lib64/jvm/jre/bin:/usr/lib/mit/bin:/usr/lib/mit/sbin
# log a starting message
logger start of $0
```

Notice the use of [logger(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/logger.1.html) - and you should use it more wisely to get appropriate log messages under `/var/log`

BTW, your `PATH` is ridiculously too long. Such a long `PATH` is messy (and might slow down your shells) and could be a security risk; my recommendation would be to have a much shorter one (perhaps as short as `$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:/bin:/usr/bin`) and add appropriate symlinks or scripts in e.g. `$HOME/bin/` or `/usr/local/bin/` using explicit program paths.

Notice that `sudo` could be used in a crontab job (but that is often unwise) and then probably should be configured in `/etc/sudoers` ; perhaps you should prefer `/bin/su` (see [su(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/su.1.html)...) in some shell script.

Read also more about [setuid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid). Sometimes it is wiser to write in C a wrapper setuid- program using it (with [setreuid(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setreuid.2.html)), but be careful (you could open huge [security holes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vulnerability_(computing)) by mistake).

Read also [*Advanced Linux Programming*](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) (freely downloadable, a bit old) then [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) to understand better how Linux works internally. You need to have a better and more clear picture of your system in your head.